# My deployment from bitbucket fails with error shown. How do I find the Azure D: drive to delete the file?

Tags: git, azure

fatal: Unable to create 'D:/home/site/repository/.git/index.lock': File exists. If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue. D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout develop --force

I don't understand the last sentence: Is it telling me to run "git checkout develop --force"? On my machine? I don't have a D: drive attached.

My deployments from other branches work (or did..., I have not pushed a new commit on them yet)

Comment: I'm assuming that you've enabled continuous deployment from a Bitbucket Git repo?

Comment: D:/home/site/ looks like an App Service deployment virtual directory path. Could you check via kudu console? yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net. In the kudu console you can browse to the directory via Debug Console

Comment: I put my comment in as an answer so that I could format it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to all of this. Yes I am doing continuous deployment from a Bitbucket Git repo, in this instance from the develop branch to an App Service just for that branch. The master and releaase branches have their own App Service web apps; those deployments work. Starting from the App Service using the develop branch, I found the kudu Diagnostic Console:

```
D:\home\site\repository\.git>dir
Volume in drive D is Windows
Volume Serial Number is AC5B-1C2E

Directory of D:\home\site\repository\.git

05/15/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>          hooks
05/15/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>          info
05/15/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>          logs
05/15/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>          objects
05/15/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>          refs
05/15/2017  09:48 PM               560 config
05/15/2017  09:48 PM                73 description
05/15/2017  09:48 PM                97 FETCH_HEAD
05/15/2017  09:48 PM                24 HEAD
05/15/2017  09:48 PM            11,071 index
05/15/2017  09:48 PM               156 web.config
           6 File(s)         11,981 bytes
```

There is no index.lock file. Next I ran the git command suggested:

```
D:\home\site\repository> git checkout develop --force
Already on 'develop'
```

Then I tried thr deployment again,

```
Synchronization Request Submitted    10:07 PM
The repository for web app moneyplandev is being updated.
```

but it failed again. Saw this Activity Log output:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\MvcWebApp.csproj...
  Installing System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost 1.0.1.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0.
```

Noticed that the MvcWebApp.csproj file name is not the same as the (renamed) project name. Corrected that and tried to deploy again. Got this error now.

```
Failed to set up deployment source
Failed to set up deployment source for web app moneyplandev, using 
Bitbucket. {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 
'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: 
There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n at System.IO....
```

What now?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading from free level to basic level to get more file storage space. I was just over the 1GB threshold of the free level. So now my hobby project costs $55/mo instead of free. Just the cost of coding ASP.NET Core with React for a Web app. Worth every penny.